# What is the derivative of a real basis vector with respect to an imaginary basis vector?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let's say I have a Pseudo-Riemannian manifold with two dimensions: real space and imaginary time. Let's further say space is related to time through the formula$$x=-\alpha t^2$$How would I express the tangent vector? My initial approach is:$$\frac{dx}{idt}=-2\alpha t$$$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-i2\alpha t$$I believe this would allow me to work with the time coordinates as if they were real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for updating your problem statement, but I don't understand the setup.  Is this manifold locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb C$, and you have "trajectories" embedded in it that are described by $x = -\alpha t^2$?  You don't describe $\alpha$, implicitly a scalar, but perhaps you know that $\alpha$ is real? positive?

Comment: @hardmath - $\alpha$ is a positive, real constant. $x$ is the extent (size) of the spatial dimension, $t$ is the time coordinate, so the size of the spatial component of the manifold is a function of time. That should make $dx/dt$ the tangent vector in the space-time direction (that is, the partial derivative of the tangent space with respect to time, as I understand the concept).

Comment: Does _real space and imaginary time_ refer to the Minkowski metric $g=dx^2-dt^2$ on the real plane with coordinates $(x, t)$? If so, perhaps you're thinking of _Wick rotation_, i.e., introducing $s = it$ so that $g=dx^2+ds^2$ is Riemannian? Whether or no, we have $\frac{dx}{dt} = -2\alpha t$ as dictated by calculus, but we do have $x=\alpha s^2$, so $\frac{dx}{i\,dt}=\frac{dx}{ds}=2\alpha s=2i\alpha t$, in accord with the chain rule.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - Why can't $s=-it$?

Comment: We could choose $s = -it$, though of course that wouldn't be the same $s$. My reason was just to get a formal expression $\frac{dx}{i\,dt}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - So is there anything wrong with the derivation in the original post?

Comment: The conclusions are not the same...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - I'm not asking if they're the same. I'm asking if there's something in my derivation that's wrong.

Comment: Calculus tells us $\frac{dx}{dt} = -2\alpha t$ so yes, it appears something in your derivation is wrong. (My first comment lays out what I suspect what was intended. Whether time is real or imaginary is immaterial unless I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the notation.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - If I used imaginary numbers for the time coordinates and $t$ for the basis vector, then Calculus tells us that $\frac{dx}{dt}=-2\alpha t$. If I want to use real numbers for time coordinates, then the basis vector is $it$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=-i2\alpha t$, so I'm not sure I understand your statement. It seems to me like the coordinate and the basis vector should be contravariant in all instances.